# Can i use QTcpSocket again for another connection after deleteLater?

Tags: c++, qt

I try to use `QTcpSserver`, which would keep connection with **one and only one client** at a time, until the client disconnects. So, I keep the client with a member pointer in my class.

The problem arises here: In the examples I see on the internet, after `disconnected()`, it is called `deleteLater()`. Good, but I would use this class-member pointer again for another connection. Remember that the server keeps one and only one client at a time. So, what if the socket object is deleted after another connection assigned on it?

What I mean is:

```
class TcpServer(QObject* o) : public QTcpServer {
...
private:
    QTcpSocket* client;
}

void TcpServer::connected() {
    client = this->nextPendingConnection();
    this->pauseAccepting();
    connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), client, SLOT(clientDisconnected()));
}

void TcpServer::clientDisconnected() {
    client->deleteLater();
    this->resumeAccepting();
}
```

Scenario is this:

1. Client connected. So, `client = nextPendingConnection();`
2. Server paused listening. Does not accept new connection.
3. Client is disconnected. `client` needs to be released. So, `client->deleteLater()` is calleed.
4. Server continues listening.
5. New connection comes. So, I need to `client = nextPendingConnection();`

**But**, previous `client` object was deleted? Maybe? Maybe not? What if event loop tries to delete `client`, after I have assigned the new connection to it in step 5?

So, how would I keep one and only one client, while deleting previous disconnected ones?

Would it be safe if I do this?

```
void TcpServer::clientDisconnected()
{
    QSocket* ptr = client;
    ptr->deleteLater();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Based on your scenario, I think you should have a pool of tcp sockets, that you can create and delete without having to worry if the previous one has been successfully deleted. If you really want to use only one socket, you should listen to the "destroyed()" signal and only then call resumeAccepting()

Comment: "destroyed: This signal is emitted immediately before the object obj is destroyed, and can not be blocked." This means that any thing I would write inside the slot of this signal, will be called after the object is destroyed, right? So, this seems the answer of the question. I would accept if you had written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will cite Qt documentation about it:

> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop.

So `deleteLater()` is a delayed `delete`. The object is to be regarded as deleted as soon as the call `deleteLater()` was made.

Your `nextPendingConnection()` call will create another object that need to be deleted some time later.

However in your case you only allow one pending connection as you said and disallow accepting until client gets disconnected. I this case it should be safe, in other cases you could overwrite your client pointer and will lose control over it (memory leak).

Even in your case, I would prefer this solution:

```
void TcpServer::clientDisconnected()
{
    if (qobject_cast<QAbstractSocket*>(sender())) {
        sender()->deleteLater();
    }
    ...
}
```

This would also be safe if more than one connection is allowed in future changes of your application.

Comment: Does not my "Would it be safe if I do this?" part is practically the same as 'sender()' solution?

Comment: But I am stopping accepting new connections when I assign client, so that connected() is never fired until clientDisconnected() is run.

Comment: No not necessarily, because establishing a new connection doesn't mean that the previous connection is disconnected i.e. `clientDisconnected()` never called for this. But I oversaw your `pauseAccepting()` call. In this case I'm not sure what slot is called first or if there is a guarantee that disconnected is called before connected. I would suggest not to use one client pointer, or use the sender() object to refer to the correct object. I'm also not sure what happens if there are still some pending `connected` signlas in queue before `pauseAccepting()` is called.

Comment: I'm limiting pending connections to 1 with setMaxPendingConnections. But I see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: @thuga In this case yes, but may be there is more work to do in disconnected like updating some UI elements. In this case I would not connect it directly (as long as access to the socket object is required of course).

Comment: `QObject::deleteLater` is a slot, so you can just connect the `QTcpSocket::disconnected` signal directly to it. That way you won't have to check the sender and do the cast.

Comment: I'm not saying remove the `clientDisconnected` slot entirely. You can still use that to do whatever else needs to be done after disconnecting. I'm just saying you can use the `disconnected` signal to handle the destruction of the object by connecting it to the `deleteLater` slot, so you don't have to check the sender and do the cast.

Comment: @thuga Yes of course that is correct, I agree with you (+1). But one thing to consider is, access to the `sender()` object (or through the client pointer) in the `clientDisconnected` slot would no more allowed because it may already have been deleted by the also connected `deleteLater` slot.

Comment: Well actually it will still be a valid object at that point (assuming direct connections are used), because `deleteLater` does not destroy the object when called, it just schedules an event for the object to be destroyed. I'd still advise against using that object, just in case there is some piece of code between the `deleteLater` call and the point where `client` object is used in the `disconnected` slot, that makes the control return to the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand `nextPendingConnection();` will return pointer to new `QTcpSocket` class object so you have nothing to worry about.

`deleteLater()` will scheduled for deletion only your old object. `QTcpSocket* client` contains only pointer to `QTcpSocket` class object. When you calling `deleteLater()` Qt will delete only object to which `client` was pointed at time of calling this function.

Comment: My worry is, what if deleteLater() looks to the memory where client points to at the time of when deleteLater() is really running, but now then it is called?

Comment: Do not worry. It will not look for current `client`. There is no `client` and other names at execution time, just pointers. When you assign new value to `client` it will lose all connections to old object and `deleteLater()` will delete this old object later. If you forget to call `deleteLater()` all old objects will be kept in memory as a garbage.

Comment: Yeah, I also think that this must be true.